# OMNETPP has different running time with SUMO

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I found a weird question about simulation running time about omnetpp and sumo.

If I run sumo alone, it will end after 999s

[image: only sumo]

However, when I run sumo with omnetpp, the simulation will ends after 999s in omnetpp, 452s in sumo.

[image: omnetpp with sumo]
[image: sumo with omnetpp]

I'm curious why these two simulations have different running time in sumo. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Are you running the Veins example simulation that comes with Veins 5a1?

Comment: @ChristophSommer No, it's Veins 4.7.1

Comment: Unlikely. The Veins 4.7.1 example simulation has a fixed time limit of 200s. The simulation can never proceed past this time. See https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L18 for the relevant setting.

Comment: @ChristophSommer Actually I changed it to 999 since my simulation needs more time